# Automatic closing of navigation menu upon click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make this website so when I click a menu item it closes the menu automatically like when I click the X. How would I do this?

```js
(function(){
    var burger = document.querySelector('.burger-container'),
        header = document.querySelector('.header');
    
    burger.onclick = function() {
        header.classList.toggle('menu-opened');
    }
}());
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ek+Mukta:200);
body {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.4;
  background: #E1E1E1;
}

.window {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 65px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
          box-shadow: 0 0 65px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #F1F1F1;
}
.window .header {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out, background 1s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out, background 1s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
          transition-delay: 0.2s;
  z-index: 1;
}
.window .header .burger-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
          transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
.window .header .burger-container #burger {
  width: 18px;
  height: 8px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: -4px auto 0;
  top: 50%;
}
.window .header .burger-container #burger .bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background: #FFF;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
          transition-delay: 0s;
}
.window .header .burger-container #burger .bar.topBar {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
          transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
}
.window .header .burger-container #burger .bar.btmBar {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(6px) rotate(0deg);
          transform: translateY(6px) rotate(0deg);
}
.window .header .icon {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 22px;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.window .header .icon.icon-bag {
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
          transform: translateX(0px);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99), -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.65s;
          transition-delay: 0.65s;
}
.window .header ul.menu {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0px 48px 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.window .header ul.menu li.menu-item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
  margin-top: 5px;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.15) translateY(-30px);
          transform: scale(1.15) translateY(-30px);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99), -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition: opacity 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99), -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99), opacity 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99), opacity 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99), -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
}
.window .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.49s;
          transition-delay: 0.49s;
}
.window .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.42s;
          transition-delay: 0.42s;
}
.window .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.35s;
          transition-delay: 0.35s;
}
.window .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.28s;
          transition-delay: 0.28s;
}
.window .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.21s;
          transition-delay: 0.21s;
}
.window .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.14s;
          transition-delay: 0.14s;
}
.window .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(7) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.07s;
          transition-delay: 0.07s;
}
.window .header ul.menu li.menu-item a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: "Ek Mukta", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 2.35;
  font-weight: 200;
  width: 100%;
}
.window .header.menu-opened {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in, background 0.5s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in, background 0.5s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.25s;
          transition-delay: 0.25s;
}
.window .header.menu-opened .burger-container {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
          transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.window .header.menu-opened .burger-container #burger .bar {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
          transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.window .header.menu-opened .burger-container #burger .bar.topBar {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(4px) rotate(45deg);
          transform: translateY(4px) rotate(45deg);
}
.window .header.menu-opened .burger-container #burger .bar.btmBar {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(3px) rotate(-45deg);
          transform: translateY(3px) rotate(-45deg);
}
.window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1) translateY(0px);
          transform: scale(1) translateY(0px);
  opacity: 1;
}
.window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.27s;
          transition-delay: 0.27s;
}
.window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.34s;
          transition-delay: 0.34s;
}
.window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.41s;
          transition-delay: 0.41s;
}
.window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.48s;
          transition-delay: 0.48s;
}
.window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.55s;
          transition-delay: 0.55s;
}
.window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.62s;
          transition-delay: 0.62s;
}
.window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(7) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.69s;
          transition-delay: 0.69s;
}
.window .header.menu-opened .icon.icon-bag {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(75px);
          transform: translateX(75px);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
          transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
.window .content {
  font-family: "Ek Mukta", sans-serif;
  padding: 67px 4% 0;
  text-align: justify;
  overflow: scroll;
  max-height: 100%;
}
.window .content::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
.window .content h2 {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.window .content img {
  width: 95%;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 75px auto 75px;
}
.window .content img:nth-of-type(2) {
  margin: 75px auto;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .window {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 0px;
  }
  .window .header {
    position: fixed;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="window">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="burger-container">
      <div id="burger">
        <div class="bar topBar"></div>
        <div class="bar btmBar"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="icon icon-apple"></div>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Mac</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">iPad</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">iPhone</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Watch</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">TV</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Music</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Support</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="shop icon icon-bag"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="content"> <img src="https://images.apple.com/v/ipad-air-2/c/images/overview/performance_large.png" alt=""/>
    <h2>Thin. Light. Epic.</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas recusandae ullam repellat, soluta, reprehenderit suscipit reiciendis minus ratione alias dolor eveniet rerum.</p><img src="https://images.apple.com/v/ipad-air-2/c/images/overview/design_large.png" alt=""/>
    <p> Consectetur adipisicing elit. Est earum dicta officiis ratione qui non perspiciatis necessitatibus laborum culpa ad. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste explicabo laborum non vel, aperiam, nemo esse harum officiis, temporibus quae, delectus dolorem laboriosam eligendi exercitationem aliquam eveniet autem facilis? Iure pariatur iusto ipsum aut, accusantium rerum. Ipsum officiis voluptatibus assumenda placeat obcaecati. Voluptas explicabo optio repellendus minima sunt, ducimus suscipit, labore ratione eum officia molestias!</p>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet quidem magnam aut corporis voluptate! Et similique iste, molestiae illo nemo adipisci molestias, iure accusantium, sit expedita fugiat aliquam dolore! Odit perferendis, earum quaerat inventore ut error placeat sunt dignissimos dicta.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[codepen.io/swarm/pen/aqNGxO](http://codepen.io/swarm/pen/aqNGxO)

Comment: We are here not to write you the whole code! Show us what you got/ what you have tried.

Comment: i tried to but the user interface for posting code was very weird i couldnt figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Initilize click event handlers for every list item.

```
var listItems = document.querySelectorAll('.menu li');
for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
    listItems[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        header.classList.toggle('menu-opened');
    });
}
```

Working [pen](https://codepen.io/sygn/pen/KQXeGw)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another event to the menu, so that when you click on a link it toogles the menu:

```js
(function(){
    var burger = document.querySelector('.burger-container'),
        header = document.querySelector('.header'),
        menuLinks = document.querySelector('ul.menu');
    
    burger.onclick = function() {
        header.classList.toggle('menu-opened');
    }
    
    menuLinks.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        if (e.target.nodeName == 'A') {
            header.classList.toggle('menu-opened');
        }
        
    });
}());
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ek+Mukta:200);
body {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.4;
  background: #E1E1E1;
}

.window {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 65px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
          box-shadow: 0 0 65px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #F1F1F1;
}
.window .header {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out, background 1s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out, background 1s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
          transition-delay: 0.2s;
  z-index: 1;
}
.window .header .burger-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
          transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
.window .header .burger-container #burger {
  width: 18px;
  height: 8px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: -4px auto 0;
  top: 50%;
}
.window .header .burger-container #burger .bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background: #FFF;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
          transition-delay: 0s;
}
.window .header .burger-container #burger .bar.topBar {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
          transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
}
.window .header .burger-container #burger .bar.btmBar {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(6px) rotate(0deg);
          transform: translateY(6px) rotate(0deg);
}
.window .header .icon {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 22px;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.window .header .icon.icon-bag {
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
          transform: translateX(0px);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99), -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.65s;
          transition-delay: 0.65s;
}
.window .header ul.menu {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0px 48px 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.window .header ul.menu li.menu-item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
  margin-top: 5px;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.15) translateY(-30px);
          transform: scale(1.15) translateY(-30px);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99), -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition: opacity 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99), -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99), opacity 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99), opacity 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99), -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
}
.window .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.49s;
          transition-delay: 0.49s;
}
.window .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.42s;
          transition-delay: 0.42s;
}
.window .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.35s;
          transition-delay: 0.35s;
}
.window .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.28s;
          transition-delay: 0.28s;
}
.window .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.21s;
          transition-delay: 0.21s;
}
.window .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.14s;
          transition-delay: 0.14s;
}
.window .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(7) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.07s;
          transition-delay: 0.07s;
}
.window .header ul.menu li.menu-item a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: "Ek Mukta", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 2.35;
  font-weight: 200;
  width: 100%;
}
.window .header.menu-opened {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in, background 0.5s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in, background 0.5s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.25s;
          transition-delay: 0.25s;
}
.window .header.menu-opened .burger-container {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
          transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.window .header.menu-opened .burger-container #burger .bar {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
          transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.window .header.menu-opened .burger-container #burger .bar.topBar {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(4px) rotate(45deg);
          transform: translateY(4px) rotate(45deg);
}
.window .header.menu-opened .burger-container #burger .bar.btmBar {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(3px) rotate(-45deg);
          transform: translateY(3px) rotate(-45deg);
}
.window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1) translateY(0px);
          transform: scale(1) translateY(0px);
  opacity: 1;
}
.window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.27s;
          transition-delay: 0.27s;
}
.window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.34s;
          transition-delay: 0.34s;
}
.window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.41s;
          transition-delay: 0.41s;
}
.window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.48s;
          transition-delay: 0.48s;
}
.window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.55s;
          transition-delay: 0.55s;
}
.window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.62s;
          transition-delay: 0.62s;
}
.window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(7) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.69s;
          transition-delay: 0.69s;
}
.window .header.menu-opened .icon.icon-bag {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(75px);
          transform: translateX(75px);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
          transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
.window .content {
  font-family: "Ek Mukta", sans-serif;
  padding: 67px 4% 0;
  text-align: justify;
  overflow: scroll;
  max-height: 100%;
}
.window .content::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
.window .content h2 {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.window .content img {
  width: 95%;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 75px auto 75px;
}
.window .content img:nth-of-type(2) {
  margin: 75px auto;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .window {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 0px;
  }
  .window .header {
    position: fixed;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="window">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="burger-container">
      <div id="burger">
        <div class="bar topBar"></div>
        <div class="bar btmBar"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="icon icon-apple"></div>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Mac</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">iPad</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">iPhone</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Watch</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">TV</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Music</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Support</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="shop icon icon-bag"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="content"> <img src="https://images.apple.com/v/ipad-air-2/c/images/overview/performance_large.png" alt=""/>
    <h2>Thin. Light. Epic.</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas recusandae ullam repellat, soluta, reprehenderit suscipit reiciendis minus ratione alias dolor eveniet rerum.</p><img src="https://images.apple.com/v/ipad-air-2/c/images/overview/design_large.png" alt=""/>
    <p> Consectetur adipisicing elit. Est earum dicta officiis ratione qui non perspiciatis necessitatibus laborum culpa ad. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste explicabo laborum non vel, aperiam, nemo esse harum officiis, temporibus quae, delectus dolorem laboriosam eligendi exercitationem aliquam eveniet autem facilis? Iure pariatur iusto ipsum aut, accusantium rerum. Ipsum officiis voluptatibus assumenda placeat obcaecati. Voluptas explicabo optio repellendus minima sunt, ducimus suscipit, labore ratione eum officia molestias!</p>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet quidem magnam aut corporis voluptate! Et similique iste, molestiae illo nemo adipisci molestias, iure accusantium, sit expedita fugiat aliquam dolore! Odit perferendis, earum quaerat inventore ut error placeat sunt dignissimos dicta.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the codepen: [link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wyrXEZ)

Comment: Wow thanks so helpful. Sorry I have a flu right now and my brains not working. I appreciate your help so much.